# Azure DevOps dashboard markdown widget - adding custom image

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I'd like to be able to add custom images in my markdown widget from the dashboard using files I can upload somewhere in Azure DevOps so that the URL references the filename (e.g. /.../../sample.png). Is there any way to host an image file on Azure that can be referenced in the markdown widget?

Answer (score 0):

You can upload your images to your repository or wiki. For example:

1.Upload files:

[image]

2.Right click the image and copy the image address.

Repository:
[image]

Wiki:

[image]

3.Add a markdown widget and insert the image:`![Text](URL)`

Here is the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/markdown-guidance?view=azure-devops#images).

Comment: Is it possible to reference the image file from the repo directly into the custom markdown widget (without selecting a README)?

Comment: @AuthenticReplica Ah, I remembered my previous way. I updated my answer. Now, you can reference the image file directly